# Make View and Sub View Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have the following code to create my window, my view and my sub view programmatically.  The problem is my subview "filterView2" when it is added `[filterView addSubview:filterView2];` crashes on that line.  Is there something I forgot to include or did wrong? thanks!

```
    NSRect mainFrame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
    NSRect helpFrame = NSZeroRect;
    float width = 600;
    float height = 400;
    helpFrame.origin.x = (mainFrame.size.width - width) / 2.0;
    helpFrame.origin.y = 260.0;
    helpFrame.size.width = width;
    helpFrame.size.height = height; 

    helpWindow2 = [[BrightnessView windowWithFrame:helpFrame] retain];

    // Configure window.
    [helpWindow2 setReleasedWhenClosed:YES];
    [helpWindow2 setHidesOnDeactivate:NO];
    [helpWindow2 setCanHide:NO];
    [helpWindow2 setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces];
    [helpWindow2 setIgnoresMouseEvents:YES];
    [helpWindow2 setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    [helpWindow2 setOpaque:NO];


    // Configure contentView.
    NSView *filterView = [helpWindow2 contentView];
    [filterView setWantsLayer:YES];
    //add subview
    NSView *filterView2 = [helpWindow2 contentView];
    [filterView addSubview:filterView2];

    //CALayer for filterView
    CALayer *theLayer = [CALayer layer];
    theLayer.opacity = 0;
    [filterView setLayer:theLayer];
    CGColorRef bgColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0, 200, 255, 1);
    theLayer.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    CGColorRelease(bgColor);
    theLayer.borderColor = CGColorGetConstantColor(kCGColorWhite);
    theLayer.cornerRadius = 8.0;

    float helpOpacity = (([NSApp isActive] ? 1 : 0));
    [[[helpWindow2 contentView] layer] setOpacity:helpOpacity];


    [window addChildWindow:helpWindow2 ordered:NSWindowAbove];
```

Comment: the helpWindow2 function "contentView", does that allocate a new version of a view or atleast retain it? and what kind of crash are we talking about here? EXC_BAD_aLLOC? Provide more info about the crash and how the "contentView" function/property/variable looks. need to know what it is

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS is the error message and the variable is just the (id)contentView

Comment: usally when u get bad_access it's cus you are trying to access something that's not retained(retain count < 1) due to that you released the memory (for example). in this case you actually have to look at your design. should a view be it's own subview? doesn't really sound right to me, so try to create a new instance of the contentView that you put into your object, you can even do a copy of it so that you dont loose anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `filterView` and `filterView2` are the same object, which causes an exception. You cannot add a view as a subview of itself.

Comment: so then how can I turn filterView2 into strictly a subview?

Comment: The most straight-forward way to create an `NSView` is to call `[[NSView alloc] initWithFrame: ...]`. However, if `filterView2` is a _subclass_ of `NSView`, it may have a different designated initializer. You should know what kind of view you want `filterView2` to be.